# Emulate user actions on a running desktop application

Tags: c#, java, c++, vb.net

I have a program coded in Java, its .exe only I have no access to its codes. I just want to automate some user inputs such as clicking some buttons, entering and reading input/text fields and check for any popups (if it comes). Could you please tell me how do I do it using Java or C# or C++ or VB or any other language.

My question is simple, I want to perform user actions on a running desktop application using any programming language available. Request you guys not to talk about QTP!!! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**AutoIt**](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) should be a good pick for such automation:

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for
> automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a
> combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control
> manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or
> reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is
> also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of
> Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying “runtimes” required!
>
> AutoIt
> was initially designed for PC “roll out” situations to reliably
> automate and configure thousands of PCs. Over time it has become a
> powerful language that supports complex expressions, user functions,
> loops and everything else that veteran scripters would expect.